# What's the meaning of 高冷?

Tags: translation

Could anyone tell me, what's the meaning of this word: 
高冷?
Haven't found any translation in the dictionary or any explanations.

Comment: What's the context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an internet slang, so you can't find it on a normal dictionary.

> 高 refers to 高高在上,高傲, which mean "to be arrogant", "to have an attitude of looking down upon someone"
>
> 冷 refers to 冷漠,冷冰冰, which mean "to be indifferent", "unconcern"

so 高冷 basically means a cold attitude.

Comment: Search 高冷 on Google to enter a world of internet slang.

Answer (score 2):

How about "aloof"? In addition to cold and distant, the person also puts him/herself on a higher position than the listener.

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

高冷 is abbreviated from 高贵冷艳

高 means 高贵, which means "noble"

冷 means 冷艳, which means "beautiful and not easy to get close"

高冷 is usually used in conversation with friends as a joke. Usually not a bad word.

Answer (score 1):

高 冷 means standing on the fridge (tall and cold )  :p

Comment: More like a snow-covered mountain?

Answer (score 0):

"Gao Leng" means a man who is an inward-looking person. Someone occasionally pretends to be "Gao Leng".